# Redux: using different reducers for a component

Tags: reactjs, redux, code-reuse

I've got a component UsersList which I'd like to reuse with two different reducers - one for listing regular users (state.users.x) and one for listing administrators (state.adminusers.x). The display is the same in both cases, but the state is in different places and different api actions apply (different endpoints with different business rules).

How can I write my component so it can use either reducer?

Comment: Reducer itself is state container, it is not responsible for API calls. If you want to access different reducers, you can subscribe to them in `mapStateToProps`. But for calling different API endpoints you need to have access to different actions and have a conditional statement in `componentDidMount` to call them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write the UsersList component as normal, but do not connect it to redux.

For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import UserInviteRow from 'jsx/components/Lib/Users/UserInviteRow';

export class UsersList extends Component {

    render() {
        const { inviteUserToOrg } = this.props;

        return (
            <Table bordered hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th className="width-200">First Name</th>
                        <th className="width-250">Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th className="width-150">Last Login</th>
                        <th className="width-100">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <UserInviteRow invitefxn={ inviteUserToOrg }/>
                    { this.renderRows() }
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        );
    }

    renderRows() {
        const { usersList } = this.props;
        if( ! usersList.length ) {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan="5">
                        <em>No users exist for this non-profit</em>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        }

        return usersList.map( (user) => {
            return (
                <tr key={user.key}>
                    <td>{user.firstName}</td>
                    <td>{user.lastName}</td>
                    <td>{user.correspondenceEmailAddress}</td>
                    <td>{ (user.lastSeen) ? formatTime(user.lastSeen) : '' }</td>
                    <td className="text-center">
                        { this.renderRemoveButton( user ) }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        });
    }

    renderRemoveButton(user) {
        const { currentUser } = this.props;
        if( currentUser.key === user.key ) {
            // users cannot remove themselves
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <a className="text-danger" onClick={ () => { this.removeUser(user) } }>
                <em className="fa fa-times" />
            </a>
        );
    }

    removeUser( user ) {
        this.props.removeUserFromOrg(user.key);
    }
}

export default UsersList;
```

2. Make sure both your reducers implement the action functions you use, in this case `inviteUserToOrg` and `removeUserFromOrg`.
3. Create new container components connected to each reducer

For example:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { 
    inviteUserToOrg, 
    removeUserFromOrg 
} as actions from 'jsx/redux/modules/nonadminUsers'; 
import UsersList from 'jsx/components/Lib/Users/UsersList';

var NonadminUserList = connect(
  state => {
    return {
      usersList: state.users.usersList,
    };
  },
  actions
)(UsersList);

export default NonadminUserList;
```

and

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { 
    inviteUserToOrg, 
    removeUserFromOrg 
} as actions from 'jsx/redux/modules/adminUsers';
import UsersList from 'jsx/components/Lib/Users/UsersList';

var AdminUserList = connect(
    state => {
        return {
            usersList: state.adminusers.usersList,
        };
    },
    actions
)(UsersList);

export default AdminUserList;
```

Now changes to your presentation component, UsersList, will affect both container components and each container component can reference it's own reducer state and actions.

Comment: As a side note, after spending more time with redux I've come to the conclusion that, while this technically works, it's a pretty ugly fix; and, as a general rule these issues can be avoided by preferring to pass data to components as props and only connecting your highest level view components.